# Firestore pagination startAfter(DocumentSnapshot) working in java but not in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I am trying to convert one Android Firestore project from java to kotlin. But got stuck in pagination part, where startAfter(DocumentSnapshot) with java code is working fine. But the kotlin one is giving only first 3 result. StartAfter(DocumentSnapshot) part is not working.

If you could please point out where am i going wrong in Kotlin,it would be very helpful.

This is the **java code** which is working perfectly

```
 public void loadNotes(View v) {
    Query query;
    if (lastResult == null) {
        query = notebookRef.orderBy("priority")
                .limit(3);
    } else {
        query = notebookRef.orderBy("priority")
                .startAfter(lastResult)
                .limit(3);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "loadNotes: "+ query);
    query.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    String data = "";
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        Notee note = documentSnapshot.toObject(Notee.class);
                        note.setDocumentId(documentSnapshot.getId());
                        String documentId = note.getDocumentId();
                        String title = note.getTitle();
                        String description = note.getDescription();
                        int priority = note.getPriority();
                        data += "ID: " + documentId
                                + "\nTitle: " + title + "\nDescription: " + description
                                + "\nPriority: " + priority + "\n\n";
                    }
                    if (queryDocumentSnapshots.size() > 0) {
                        data += "___________\n\n";
                        textViewData.append(data);
                        lastResult = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments()
                                .get(queryDocumentSnapshots.size() - 1);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

And this is the **Kotlin** one,which is not working.

```
 private fun loadNotes() {
    val query = if (lastResult == null) {
        notebookRef
            .orderBy("priority")
            .limit(3)
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadNotes: ${lastResult!!.id}")
        notebookRef
            .orderBy("priority")
            .startAfter(lastResult)
            .limit(3)

    }

    Log.d(TAG, "loadNotes: $query")


    query.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { QuerySnapshot ->
            var text = ""
            for (queryDocumentSnapshot in QuerySnapshot) {
                val note: Note = queryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(Note::class.java)
                note.docID = queryDocumentSnapshot.id

                val title = note.title
                val description = note.description
                val priority = note.priority
                text += "ID: ${note.docID} \n Title : $title\n Description :$description\n" +
                        "Priority :$priority \n"

            }
            if (QuerySnapshot.size() > 0) {
                text += "---------------\n\n"
                textView_data.append(text)
                lastResult = QuerySnapshot.documents[QuerySnapshot.size() - 1]
            }
        }
}
```

Hope to get some help

Thanks

Required codes for testing : [JavaActivity](https://gist.github.com/Shijilal/f3979ad03d6c55aed5d3856fe237cef7) [KotlinActivity](https://gist.github.com/Shijilal/dd4a902eeedd02e7d7b141c2c1c269aa) [Note Model](https://gist.github.com/Shijilal/c037505e10d69bb691f9054863fe1ea2) and [activity_main.xml](https://gist.github.com/Shijilal/169e5c1afde2edbee3d420e957cf6da4)

Comment: For true kotlin support, you could swap `onSucessListeners` with `kotlin coroutines.` [here](https://medium.com/@ericampire/firestore-pagination-with-paging-3-762e371cc57f) is an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement it diferently in Kotlin. instead of keeping a reference to the last result you have to keep a reference to the query you create with the lastResult.

remove the global lastResult and replace it with:

```
private var query: Query? = null
```

then implemente the LoadNotes like this:

```
private fun loadNotes() {
    if(query == null){
        query = notebookRef.orderBy("priority").limit(3)
    }
    query!!.get().addOnSuccessListener { QuerySnapshot ->
        var text = ""
        for (queryDocumentSnapshot in QuerySnapshot) {
            val note: Note = queryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(Note::class.java)
            note.docID = queryDocumentSnapshot.id

            val title = note.title
            val description = note.description
            val priority = note.priority
            text += "ID: ${note.docID}\nTitle: $title \nDescription: $description"+
            "\nPriority: $priority\n"

        }
        if (QuerySnapshot.size() > 0) {
            text += "---------------\n\n"
            textView_data.append(text)
            val lastResult = QuerySnapshot.documents[QuerySnapshot.size() - 1]
            query = notebookRef.orderBy("priority").startAfter(lastResult).limit(3)
        }
    }
}
```

the last 2 lines is what makes it work. Honesty, i still dont understand why it does not work like in Java, but at least this implementation works. The [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#kotlin+ktx_3) also recomends to implement it like this.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. but still the question remains ,why the earlier code is not working. :(

Answer (score 6):

Well, after suffering the same issue. It was solved by using the non-null cast (!!). For example:

```
val query = transactionsCollection
            .orderBy(Field.CREATED, Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .startAfter(lastDocument!!)
            .limit(PAGE_SIZE)
```

In your case it would be:

```
 query = notebookRef.orderBy("priority")
                .startAfter(lastResult!!)
                .limit(3);
```

with that it is working on Kotlin.

Comment: finally the only answer which works! Thanks a ton! (I am not sure why it doesn't work in the first place though).

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected. There's no difference between what you're doing in Kotlin from java. You specified the limit to be 3 in both cases.

If there's anything wrong it will be on your logic.

Comment: My logic is correct,that why i clearly mentioned java code is working fine.

Comment: @Shijilal The query part from java code is the same as in the kotlin code, and should give the same result. If there's a problem it's in another part of your code.

Comment: Its just a button click and its not affected by other codes. I have updated by question with all the required codes in full for checking and testing purpose.